# Filter query words(multi-lang) which I don't want Elasticsearch use for search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this kind of query. When I pass query argument like `TOO Big House` I don't want Elastic to search by word `TOO`. Because there are a lot of this kind names with `TOO` in begining. There is nothing about it in documentation. Is it posible in ElasticSearch?

```json
{"bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "consignorOrganizationName": {
                            "query":"?0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
}}
```

Field from index:

```json
"properties": {
     "consignorOrganizationName": {
          "type": "text"
     }
}
```

---

After I figured out that the problem can be because of multi-lang stopwords. I tried this and looks like this works for me. But I'm not sure if this approach is good

```json
"analyzer": {
    "company_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer":  "standard",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "russian_stop",
            "english_stop"
        ]
    }
},
"filter": {
    "russian_stop": {
        "type":       "stop",
        "ignore_case": true,
        "stopwords":  ["ТОО"] 
    },
    "english_stop": {
        "type":       "stop",
        "ignore_case": true,
        "stopwords":  ["TOO"] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `consignorOrganizationName ` is an analyzed text field, with your query you're going to get a match also when TOO is not at the beginning. Anyhow, can't you just drop the TOO from your query value before you send the request to Elasticsearch (e.g., at the application level)?

Comment: Yes, It can be not in the begining. I just don't want this word to participate in serch in order not to show me results like `TOO SMALL TOWN` or `LITTLE TOO BASE`. Yes I can remove this in Application level, but I just wanted to rely on Elastice analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to rely on text analysis, you can create a custom analyzer with a stop token filter in which you specify your custom stopword `TOO` ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter-customize)).

```
PUT your-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "my_custom_stop_words_filter" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_custom_stop_words_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "ignore_case": true,
          "stopwords": [ "TOO" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "consignorOrganizationName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This analyser returns me 0 rows. It completely removes rows wich contains this `TOO`

Comment: Can you please share your query and explain what do you mean by removing rows that contain `TOO`?

Comment: Seems like the problem with language. I have english `TOO` and russian `ТОО`. Looks like english stopword works for me and I don't get results like `TOO SMALL TOWN`,  `LITTLE TOO BASE` with english `TOO`. But when I add russian `ТОО` in stopword list All documents which contains this russian version are not presented in result at all.